# Creating a JMeter test with multiple HTTPSampler from Java using the jmeter api

Tags: java, jmeter

Well what I`m trying to do is to replicate an app scenario with the rest api and documentation provided, where a user logins (requesting oauth authentication) and asks for basic information.
I started using the jmeter gui and got that part running good (logging and getting the info I needed) like this:
[image: jmeter gui test plan]

but now i need to do that from java with the api of jmeter and thats where im getting lost, since there isn´t much info other than the blazemeter.com post [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) the parragraph 4.3 specifically that was my starting point, and my code is very similar to it so I will use it as example of what I have done so far

```
// HTTP Sampler 1
HTTPSampler httpSampler1 = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler.setDomain("example1.com");
httpSampler.setPort(80);
httpSampler.setPath("/");
httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
RegexExtractor regex1=new RegexExtractor();
regex1.setRegex("regex1");
regex1.setRefName("REGEX1");
regex1.setTemplate("$1$");
regex1.setMatchNumber("0");
regex1.setDefaultValue("false");
regex1.useHeaders();

// HTTP Sampler 2
HTTPSampler httpSampler2 = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler2.setDomain("example.com");
httpSampler2.setPort(80);
httpSampler2.setPath("/2");
httpSampler2.setMethod("GET");
RegexExtractor regex2=new RegexExtractor();
regex2.setRegex("regex2");
regex2.setRefName("REGEX2");
regex2.setTemplate("$1$");
regex2.setMatchNumber("0");
regex2.setDefaultValue("false");
regex2.useHeaders();

// HTTP Sampler 3
HTTPSampler httpSampler3 = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler3.setDomain("example.com");
httpSampler3.setPort(80);
httpSampler3.setPath("/3");
httpSampler3.setMethod("GET");
RegexExtractor regex3=new RegexExtractor();
regex3.setRegex("regex3");
regex3.setRefName("REGEX3");
regex3.setTemplate("$1$");
regex3.setMatchNumber("0");
regex3.setDefaultValue("false");
regex3.useHeaders();

// Loop Controller
LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler1);
loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler2);
loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler3);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.initialize();

// Thread Group
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

// Test Plan
TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");

// Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler1", httpSampler1);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler2", httpSampler2);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler3", httpSampler3);

// Run Test Plan
jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
jmeter.run();
```

Almost the same, I assume one has to add the elements to the same LoopController to simulate a user going from url on url and the same thread group(as they represent a user), also assuming that I have to add them in order to the testPlanTree.

When i run it just like above, only sampler #3 is executed (I´m checkng with wireshark), after that tryied running sampler #1 and #2 and only sampler #1 was executed, this behavior lost me. I commented parts and executed them one at a time and they do get executed the request #2 and #3 well dont do much more than returning error code since they need info from previous rest call and they dont work all together.

I spend some time reading the documentation but it was hard to decipher and google didn´t got me far looking for examples similar to what im trying to do.

I´ve spend the past two days with these, feeling frustrated, any help will be welcome.

Comment: Notice all the comments on the link saying the code from 4.3 doesn't work?

Comment: Writing jmeter in java is pretty advanced, you need to understand test plan hierarchy properly first. The code above (and on the link page) seems to add elements to the test plan root that are not valid. It starts out building a hierarchy, then just seems to slap it altogether in some weird fashion. Not sure which version of JMeter this would have run successfully on.

Comment: Your original test plan and the java code version have nothing in common. At least try and create similar test plans using the different methods, and show that you already understand one or the other.  The question as it stands implies you are beginner at both jmeter and java, so why would you be learning how to convert one to the other?

Comment: @CharlieS Yes im a beginner at both  and decided to give a try even though the comments, at work other juniors an me need to learn this. As I understand right now, I made that thread group with all the samplers because we want to emulate those steps in order, regexExtractor is postprocessor so each sampler has the regex  for the response expected, so far for what i think i know it is similar, please do tell what you think it's not. Any input is well receivied, And if you know of another set of examples/doc newbie friendly or not, im all ears

Comment: Your first test plan has no loop controller, yet the java code is based on a loop controller. How do you think they are similar? Either try to convert your jmeter test plan to java, or try to write the java as a jmeter test plan. You need to understand one of them in principle first, but you are just guessing.

Comment: `threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);` is used to set the loop count of thread group (in the GUI is loop variable of thread group screen) i finally had to dive in the source of jmeter. Once I properly setup the regex elements in each sampler i will upload the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes:

- add the samplers as children of LoopController instead of adding it to TestPlan element.
- add the loopController as child of thread group
- add the thread group as child of Test plan

Alternatively, Try using this library :

- https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl

Using Maven, add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>us.abstracta.jmeter</groupId>
   <projectId>jmeter-java-dsl</projectId>
   <version>0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
 import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
 import static us.abstracta.jmeter.javadsl.JmeterDsl.*;

 import java.time.Duration;
 import org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes.Type;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
 import us.abstracta.jmeter.javadsl.TestPlanStats;

 public class PerformanceTest {

   @Test
   public void testPerformance() throws IOException {
     TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
        threadGroup(2, 10,
        httpSampler("http://my.service")
           .post("{\"name\": \"test\"}", Type.APPLICATION_JSON)
     ),
      //this is just to log details of each request stats
     jtlWriter("test.jtl")
     ).run();
              assertThat(stats.overall().elapsedTimePercentile99()).isLessThan(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
  }

 }
```